# ViewModelProvider.get is very slow

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working on a code for a new job and we have a severe performance problem on that Android app. There is a view, which, when opened, returns `oeuvreDetailViewModel.oeuvre?.title` as `null` more often than not.

```kotlin
// Class attributes
private val oeuvreViewModel: OeuvreViewModel by viewModels()
private lateinit var oeuvreDetailViewModel: OeuvreDetailViewModel
private val safeArgs : OeuvreDetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    // Obtain the artwork associated with `safeArgs.itemSelected.id`
    oeuvreDetailViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        OeuvreDetailViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, safeArgs.itemSelected.id)
    ).get(OeuvreDetailViewModel::class.java)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentOeuvreItemBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_oeuvre_item, container, false).apply {
        viewModel = oeuvreDetailViewModel
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        callback = getProperCallback(fab)
    }

    return binding.root
}
```

So I tried a while loop that runs every 0.03 seconds and tries again as long as the attribute is `null`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    // Obtain the artwork associated with `safeArgs.itemSelected.id`
    oeuvreDetailViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        OeuvreDetailViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, safeArgs.itemSelected.id)
    ).get(OeuvreDetailViewModel::class.java)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentOeuvreItemBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_oeuvre_item, container, false).apply {
        viewModel = oeuvreDetailViewModel
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        callback = getProperCallback(fab)

        while (oeuvreDetailViewModel.oeuvre?.title == null) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                viewModel = oeuvreDetailViewModel
                callback = getProperCallback(fab)
            }, 30L)
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { view ->
            view.findNavController().navigateUp()
        }
    }

    return binding.root
}
```

But now the execution stops on the `while` for several seconds. Why is this so slow?

`OeuvreDetailsViewModel`'s relevant code:

```kotlin
class OeuvreDetailViewModel(application: Application, private var oeuvreId: Int): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var isArt = false;
    private var isPlaces = false;
    private var isHeritages = false;

    private val repository: OeuvreRepository
    var oeuvre: Oeuvre? = null
    init {
        // Gets reference to OeuvreDao from OeuvreDatabase to construct
        // the correct OeuvreRepository.
        val oeuvreDao = OeuvreDatabase.getDatabase(
            application,
            viewModelScope
        ).oeuvreDAO()
        repository = OeuvreRepository.getInstance(oeuvreDao)
        getOeuvre()
    }

    private fun getOeuvre() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            oeuvre = repository.getArticleById(oeuvreId)
        }
    }


    fun updateTarget(oeuvreId: Int, target: Int?) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updateTarget(oeuvreId,target)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many misues/misconceptions about coroutines and blocking of threads in this code, I don't really know where to start. I think you need to do more review of coroutine basics to understand them better before attempting to use them. It is a bit of a steep learning curve for beginners. Suggested search terms:  "what does it mean to block a thread", "why you can't block the main thread on android", "blocking vs. suspending code in kotlin coroutines", "asynchronous code", "race condition".

Comment: It is extremely weird that your database factory function takes a CoroutineScope parameter. That seems like a recipe for disaster if your database is a singleton.